# How to connect to a SQL Server from another computer using SSMS with only hostname?

Tags: sql-server, aws, amazon-ec2

I set up a VM server computer on AWS EC2 and got a SQL Express Server running on it on port 1433. I made sure to allow TCP/IP requests and allowed TCP port 1433 through the firewall along with UDP port 1434. I then created a second VM computer on AWS EC2 - same VPC, security group, and subnet - and installed SSMS.

I also made sure that to put the two computers in the same workgroup in windows, and made them discoverable.

I can connect to the SQL server I created via IP and port number (e.g. IPAddress\Hostname,1433) but I can't connect with just the hostname. Any ideas to what I'm missing here? I followed the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017#otherComp) to the letter and it doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried having the two EC2 VM computers ping each other by computer name and it doesn't work either.

Comment: When you have a connection method that works, why is using just the hostname so important?

Comment: I'm trying to emulate an on-premise network, where a user would presumably access the database with only the hostname. This is for testing purposes.

Comment: How about adding alias in SQL Server Configuration Manager? You may find it under SQL Native Client configuration

Comment: I tried adding the alias. Didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A user should presumably access the database using the method that works. :-) Sometimes you'll have a named instance, sometimes you'll have an Azure SQL DB, sometimes you'll have a read-only secondary connection, sometimes you'll need to access by IP instead of machine name or FQDN. These all affect the connection string. Users need to adapt or, I guess, not connect.